# Vue.js re-sort after input value

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, sorting, vuejs2

I have an html table that renders sorted by a computed property (by price).

My HTML:

```
<input v-model="inputNumber" type="number">
<table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Fruit</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Final price</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="fruit in orderFruits">
                    <td>{{ fruit.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ fruit.price }}</td>
                    <td v-if="!input">{{ fruit.price }}</td>
                    <td v-else>{{ fruit.price * inputNumber }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

My JS:

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    fruits: [{"name": "apple", "price": 5}, {"name": "banana", "price": 6},{"name": "orange", "price": 7}],
    inputNumber: null
  },

  computed: {
    orderFruits: function () {
      function compare(a, b) {
        return (a.price - b.price);
      }
      return this.fruits.slice().sort(compare);
    },
...
```

How could I re-sort my list after the value input?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You comparator should take into account `inputNumber` so that changes to that property would automatically recompute `orderFruits`. Also be sure to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for `compare()` to capture the component context within:

```js
{
  computed: {
    orderFruits: function () {
      const compare = (a, b) => {
        return this.inputNumber
          ? (a.price * this.inputNumber - b.price * this.inputNumber)
          : (a.price - b.price);
      }
      return this.fruits.slice().sort(compare);
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oNBmeyj?editors=1010)